# Why is GCC generate the code with bunch of useless JMP instruction?

Tags: assembly, avr, avr-gcc

I am currently working on a Bootloader in Atmel Studio for Atmega328P (Arduino UNO), and from the disassembly I found the following code (My bootloader starts from 0x3800):

```
--- ../../../../crt1/gcrt1.S ---------------------------------------------------
00003800  JMP 0x00003834        Jump 
00003802  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003804  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003806  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003808  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
0000380A  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
0000380C  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
0000380E  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
--- ../../../../crt1/gcrt1.S ---------------------------------------------------
00003810  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003812  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003814  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003816  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003818  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
0000381A  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
0000381C  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
0000381E  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003820  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003822  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003824  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003826  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003828  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
0000382A  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
0000382C  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
0000382E  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003830  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
00003832  JMP 0x00003979        Jump 
--- C:\Users\andy\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\CannyFlashy\CannyFlashy\CannyFlashy\Debug/.././Sketch.cpp 
int main(){
00003834  IN R28,0x3D       In from I/O location
```

Why is GCC generating such code and is there anyway to avoid them?

Comment: Those JMP instructions are the interrupt vector table. They are generated automatically when compiling from C code with Atmel Studio. I think I have read about how to remove it in one of my AVR programming books. Have to check and get to you with it.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz thanks, I'd look into those IVT

Answer (score 5):

**WHAT IS IT**

As [Javier Silva Ortíz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12188799/javier-silva-ort%C3%ADz) mentioned in the comment, it is an interrupt table placed at the most beginning of the program memory.

The first instruction is a RESET vector, and we can see the address it is pointing at. In the other words, just after reset, MCU executes first `JMP 0x00003834` instruction and moves exactly to the beginning of the program.

By the way, have a look at the other `JMP` instructions: all of them pointing at the same address, so called `__bad_interrupt()`, where the only instruction `RETI` is placed. If one of these interrupts accidentally hits (and your program have no idea what to do with this interrupt), then the single `RETI` instruction finalizes this interrupt instantly and the program returns to it's normal execution.

**AVOIDING IT**

If you are absolutely sure there are no possible interrupt hits in your Bootloader, you could avoid interrupt table, passing `CFLAGS = -nostartfiles` flag to the compiler.

**BE CAREFUL!**

*Some other things will be broken with `-nostartfiles` flag!*

The problem is that avr-gcc makes some magic at the beginning of the compiled program. There are some common operations that compiler places just after interrupt table. These operations are devided by the sections, such as `__ctors_end`, `__do_copy_data`, `__do_clear_bss` and so on. What are they needed for?

First of all, `r1` register is set to zero during `__ctors_end` section. Why is it so important? `r1` is used by default every time the compiler compares other registers with zero. Yes, avr-gcc knows about this "magical" `r1` and does not write to it, but there are some cases, when it changes (for example, the result of multiplication is placed at the r0:r1 register pair), and every time it changes, avr-gcc nullify it. Everything can go wrong if `r1` is not set to zero during startup...

The other thing done at the beginning of the program is setting to zero variables that are supposed to be zero. It is done at the `__do_clear_bss` section. Just imagine you expect something to be zero and it is not. What are the consequences?

The other important operation is to copy data from the program memory to SRAM. It is done at `__do_copy_data` section. Switching off `__do_copy_data` brokes all the static arrays.

**AND?..**

You should be very careful trying to optimize interrupt table with `-nostartfiles`. Do this only if you are 200% sure what are going on.